# How to do SASL Bind to Active Directory with mechanism as Kerberos

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I tried to bind to Active Directory using SASL bind. I wrote the following code:

```
LdapConnectionconnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(serverIP, port, false, false));
connection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true;
connection.SessionOptions.Signing = true;
connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(serverUser, serverPass);
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
connection.Bind();
```

I **want** the bind type to be **SASL with Kerberos** as the underlying mechanism. However, when I see this request in Wireshark, I see it is NTLM. Can anyone help explain why? And what should be done to SASL bind with Kerberos mechanism?

[image]

**P.S.** Test machine is in the same domain as the Active Directory machine.

Comment: Set `AuthType` to `AuthType.Kerberos` and see what happens. It will likely fail, but it may give you more information as to why.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I tried that. In that case it gives, Invalid credentials are supplied. Same credentials work otherwise.

Comment: Watch the traffic in Wireshark with it set to `Kerberos`. It may show you why the Kerberos authentication is failing.